# What does "être à + infinitive" mean?

Tags: grammaire, infinitif

I'm trying to read [this](https://journals.openedition.org/scolia/1436) article (linked to in a different French.SE question). The very first sentence gives me difficulty!

> L’autorité de Claude Muller en matière d’indéfinis **n’est plus à
> démontrer.**

deepL translates this to:

> Claude Muller's authority on the subject of indefinites **needs no
> further demonstration.**

and if I click on "needs no futher" to get an alternative translation, DeepL gives a translation that is closer to my understanding of *ne..plus* :

> Claude Muller's authority on the subject of indefinites **no longer needs to be demonstrated**.

---

I know that "à + infinitive" is called the "passive infinitive", and often follows a noun, for example "chambre à louer". It can be translated as "for ___ing", as in "room for renting". The answer to [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26331/what-does-%C3%AAtre-%C3%A0-pr%C3%A9voir-mean) question explains this in different words:

> That form "à + infinitif" expresses the goal of potentially
> accomplishing the action.
>
> Je te sers quelque chose à boire ?
>
> Something to drink

---

With this information, I'm still not able to understand deepL's translation. "à démontrer" isn't being applied to a noun. The closest translation I can guess is "Claude's authority .. no longer is for demonstrating" or "... no longer is something to potentially demonstrate". I don't see how the idea of *need* can be found in "n'est plus à démontrer".

I thought that "être à + infinitive" might be an idiom, but looking through larousse's [results](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre/31549#162299) after searching for "être à" doesn't seem to have an entry for "être à + infinitive".

<sub>(**edit**: actually, the page on Larousse *does* in fact have an entry for "être à", which (among other things) talks about obligation. I don't know why I didn't see it originally? However, the answers below are very helpful with their additional examples and their systematic elaboration about the "être à + infinitive" expressing obligation)</sub>

Questions:

1. How can I understand how "n'est plus à démontrer" can be translated to "needs no further demonstration"?
2. Is there a way I can have looked this up myself, using the Internet (eg a dictionary, or some other resource)? Or, is there a way I could have guessed the meaning of "n'est plus à démonterer"?
3. [This](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/passive-infinitive/) grammar page on the passive infinitive has example sentences, but none of these sentences has the passive infinitive attached to a verb. Can you give me example sentences where "à + infinitive" is attached to a verb, as it is with "être à démontrer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commençons par un exemple à la forme affirmative.
Je viens de repeindre les murs de ma chambre et le résultat ne me plaît pas, c'est raté, je dis :

- Ce travail est à refaire.

On peut dire que c'est une forme passive car le sujet de l'action (l'agent) n'est pas exprimé et le focus est mis sur l'action elle-même (le travail). À la forme active je dirais :

- Je dois refaire ce travail / il faut que je refasse ce travail.

**« Être à » suivi d'un infinitif peut indiquer une obligation morale <sup>1</sup>.**

Ce qu'en anglais j'exprime par :  *have to/need to* (*This needs to/has to be done again*).

Le [TLF indique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) :

> On attribue parfois au verbe *être* suivi de à + inf. actif, une valeur d'auxil. de modalité, la « modalité » (en réalité rendue plutôt par la prép. à étant celle de destination et/ou d'obligation inhérente ou extérieure, l'inf. de forme active prenant alors une valeur passive; la tournure équivaut à la construction devoir + inf. passif).

La **négation de cette obligation morale** peut s'exprimer en français par :

- Je n'ai pas besoin de le refaire.

ou si je ne veux pas exprimer le sujet actif « je » :

- C'est bon, ce n'est pas à refaire.

Dans la phrase citée dans la question l'emploi de « être à » s'explique par le fait qu'il n'y a pas besoin de citer le sujet de l'action. On pourrait tout aussi bien dire :

- Il n'y a plus besoin de démontrer l’autorité de Claude Muller.

Ma conclusion est que la traduction de DeepL qui donne *need* en traduction de « être à + infinitif » est correcte.

---

En complément de la réponse je voudrais revenir sur la remarque du TLF qui me semble importante pour qui veut approfondir la valeur de « à » dans cette tournure « être à + inf.».

Je compare ces deux phrases :

- Ce travail est à faire. (Il faut faire ce travail/*This job needs to be done*)
- Ce travail reste à faire. (Il faut encore faire ce travail. *This job still needs to be done*.)

Le verbe est différent, (être/rester) mais l'idée d'obligation demeure. Si je transforme la forme passive en forme active ou si je traduis la phrase en anglais j'introduis un adverbe de temporalité (encore/*still*) pour rendre la nuance exprimée par le verbe.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Je dis « peut » car   « Être à + inf. » peut dans d'autres cas exprimer une action en cours (« tu t'amuses et moi je suis là à t'attendre »).</sup>

Comment: your explanation that starts out explaining the passive meaning of the passive infinitive is really helpful. it helps me understand the meaning of "need". then, your explanation of negating the obligation, and then using my sentence of my original question, systematically clarifies my confusion about it. thanks for taking the effort to slowly, systematically explain this to me.

Comment: @silph You're welcome.To further your understanding I've added an explanation about the role of *à*.

Answer (score 2):

**I** *Definition from the [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_plus_%C3%AAtre_%C3%A0_d%C3%A9montrer)*

> **ne plus être à démontrer** \nə ply.z‿ɛ.tʁ‿a de.mɔ̃.tʁe\ (se conjugue → voir la conjugaison de être)
>
> Être acquis ; ne pas être contestable.
> ♦  Les conséquences du Covid-19 sur la santé ne sont plus à démontrer. Le SARS-CoV-2 a coûté à ce jour plus de 1,2 million de vies dans le monde, selon les derniers bilans officiels, dont près de 40 000 en France.

It follows that we are contending with a verbal locution, an idiom, for which there is a set meaning.

**II** - L’autorité de Claude Muller en matière d’indéfinis n’est plus à démontrer.

You say that in this sentence, the construction is not used after a noun, and so you do not understand; but it doesn't have to be.

*Examples*

- C'est une exposition à voir. ▼ Cette exposition est à voir.
- C'est un travail  à faire, personne ne l'a commencé. ▼ Ce travail est à faire, personne ne l'a encore entamé.

**III**

- "Claude's authority .. no longer is for demonstrating" or "... no longer is something to potentially demonstrate"

This is a literal translation, and it is not proper because the idea of demonstration in "plus à démontrer" is not factual, only figurative: nobody has ever  carried out a formal demonstration, but instead, the continuous process of dealing with the question has never yielded anything that could contradict the affirmations of the person in question. It is this state of affairs that is being categorized by the set expression.
The idea of "need" might not be the best in this case, but it does correspond to "être à".

- Cette marmite est à nettoyer soigneusement. → This pot needs careful cleaning.
- Ce travail n'est plus à faire, il a été sous-traité à une société spécialisée. → It is no longer needed to do this work, it's been subcontracted to a specialized firm.

Comment: 1) the copular examples, and the "need" example sentences really help me. thanks for writing them. 2) i'm unsure about *Claude Muller, qui jouit d'une autorité plus à démontrer*. unlike the original sentence, this doesn't use *ne..plus* . i'm not sure what "une autorité à démontrer" means (something like "an authority potentially to be demonstrated"?), nor what "une autorité **plus** à démontrer" ("an authority very much to be demonstrated"??). can you help me understand what this sentence means, without and with the "plus"?

Comment: another attempt of mine at translating "une autorité à démontrer" is: "an authority that someone could (or should) demonstrate". this still doesn't help me understand "une autorité **plus** à démontrer", perhaps because i don't know what the "plus" means or what it is modifying?

Comment: @silph In  most cases of such "transfert" of an idiom from one construction to another the idiom retains its charateristics; here, since you can only use the negative ("l'autorité n'est plus à démontrer"), similarly, in the noun construction you can only use the negative, the positive "une autorité à démontrer" would not mean anything. That is a principle.  In this construction "plus" is not to be taken as "more" but as "no more" because of an ellipse, that of "qui n'est" (autorité (qui n'est) plus à démontrer); (1/2)

Comment: @silph  this is as in  "Plus un moment à perdre". Nevertheless, I think that your doubting reveals something that is probably not right. I made some verifications, and couldn't find anything to support that; moreover I couldn't find one single case of "autorité plus à démontrer".  So, it must be (very) colloquial, if not downright incorrect;  it is therefore better for you to forget entirely about it. I'll remove that from my answer. (2/2)

Comment: @silph I did find an example of this elliptical construction, but it is possibly limited to certains contexts: "Tout à l'heure, je passais en voiture dans la rue, j'ai vu un type plus tout jeune,70 ans peut être… ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_beaut%C3%A9_en_plus/RKQ6QL0k8AYC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22plus+tout+jeune%22&pg=PT98&printsec=frontcover)).

Comment: it is educational for me to learn about how idioms can be transformed into different forms, and an ellipses can occur. also, Wiktionnaire is a resource that i didn't know about, and is more approachable for a beginner than the TLF dictionary. given that Wiktionnaire has the idiom "ne plus être à démontrer", it might be useful to me in future searches i make make, where WordReference and Larousse don't have certain idioms.